# Let's get critical: Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to calculate the right and left speed for a tank-like rover?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2011/how-to-calculate-right-and-left-speed-for-a-tank-like-rover)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Choosing correct power supply for Stepper Motors](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/choosing-correct-power-supply-for-stepper-motors)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [My Raspberry Pi is losing power in a surge](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/my-pi-is-losing-power-in-a-surge)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Accelerometers error (BMA020 and BMA180)](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/accelerometers-error-bma020-and-bma180)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Odd L293D behavior: Pin 16 seems to act as enable](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/odd-l293d-behavior-pin-16-seems-to-act-as-enable)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Usage of Multibeam 2D Imaging Sonar for AUVs, testing them in the pool environment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/usage-of-multibeam-2d-imaging-sonar-for-auvs-testing-them-in-the-pool-environme)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Making high CAN baud rates work](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/making-high-can-baud-rates-work)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can you have a career in robotics if you hate mechanics?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1983/can-you-have-a-career-in-robotics-if-you-hate-mechanics)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Bluetooth module HC-05 giving ERROR :(0)](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/bluetooth-module-hc-05-giving-error-0)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [SLAM without landmarks?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1985/slam-without-landmarks)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two major sorts of questions being asked here - hardware and software.
Robotic software is often very implementation specific - how many programmers are checking the unanswered question questions queue?

Broad and varied experience is sorely needed.

Hardware tends to not be as simple to define as software. Probing for information interferes with the TOS: '...But avoid Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers. Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.'